Varying sine frequency with varying amplitudes
I am simulating AFCS by injecting Sine wave with varying frequencies with varying amplitudes.
I have 128 different frequencies aith 128 different amplitudes. How do I simulate it ?
I have saved all the frequencoies and the amplitudes to a notepad doc and used a PWL function, but seems like it does not do the job.
Can I use a BV source {Am}*sin{freq} and use that to inject into my inputs ?



I've offered an answer, recently, here that discusses a method where you can just enter a frequency and it develops the sinusoidal approximation. You can change the PWM frequency, relative to the designed sinusoidal frequency, by changing another variable. I believe there are table lookups in LTspice that can be used to some advantage, using .STEP and PARAM for example. But you know your situation better than I do. So are in a better position to tell me if they would solve your problem, or not. I may misunderstand you, though. Apologies if so.

I think your question is a bit sparse on information. I have no idea what you’re trying to do.

Lets say my frequencies are
1sin(100k)
2sin(200k)
3sin(300k)
4sin(400k)
How can i do this without typying in evry single intance into LTspice ?
Basically trying to create the sine wave form with the ampitudes and the frequencies given in the graph above.

Please let me know if you know any way I can get this to work

@AerospaceElectroGuy You can use .STEP command to do that with one circuit that is re-run over and over. That will produce multiple runs that you can plot and see how they compare with each other. But I don't feel I understand enough of the goal, right now, to consider saying any more than I have. If you write more, that may change.
